# Access service on host machine from docker container

Tags: docker

I've asked a similar question on the docker forum...

https://forums.docker.com/t/access-service-on-host-machine-from-docker-container/45117

...but I'm not getting any joy and this should not be difficult. However when I google about it seems that it is difficult which seems crazy to me. So I'll ask the question in a different way...

**Host A** running docker **container A**

**Host B** running a **legacy service** exposed on **port 1234**

**container A** can access the **legacy service** on **host B** on **port 1234** (no problems)

Now I decide to run **container A** on **host B**. The crazy thing is **container A** can no longer access the legacy service provided by **host B** no matter what I try!

There must be a way to do this reliably?

**Container A** can ping **host B** fine when running on **host A or B** but when container A tries to connect to the legacy service I always get the error

> No route to host

There is no firewalls (they have been disabled) and dns works fine within container A and resolves host B to the correct IP no matter what host it is running on.

Comment: can you `curl` on port 1234 host B from host A when container A is running on B ?

Comment: I think you should try matching the final IP address via which you are trying to connect because sometime 192.168.10.1 is not same as 127.0.0.1

Comment: Benoit - yes I can

Comment: techtrainer - the service on host B is listening on all interfaces. I can use 192.168.10.X externally or 127.0.0.1 (if on host B)

Answer (score 1):

Think you have to pass the HOST to the Container when running on the same Host. For example Wordpress with "legacy" DB on Host B.

```
docker run --name wordpress --add-host=db:172.17.0.74
```

Now you can point Wordpress to DB Host: db

Comment: Does not work, same issue. Plus I now have to reference hostname "db" instead of it's well known hostname. I also have to work out the IP of the interface in the container that is the host. I still get "no route to host". For now I have started the container with network mode "host", a bodge but it works.