# Access outside port from docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/24326540#24326540), [this](https://blog.codeship.com/using-the-add-host-flag-for-dns-mapping-within-docker-containers/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458862/access-service-on-host-machine-from-docker-container).

Despite that this is asked many times, I don't understand it, and it seems inconclusive. Please consider before posting *possible duplicates*.

On my Ubuntu 16, I have a container that has to access services outside the container. It is not possible to use `--network="host"`, because that is against the purpose of using Docker for me. Plus, [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) says: "Bridge networks are usually used when your applications run in standalone containers that need to communicate", which is this case.

So by choosing the `bridge` network approach, I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/24326540#24326540) (By far the most popular Q&A found online). Where it says use the "route" command inside the container to get the Host IP:

```
export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $2}')
```

There are two issues:

1: Is this the most straight forward solution to such a trivial need?

2: I execute this in my container in my node application:

```
 await execSync("route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $2}'", (err, stdout,stderr) =>{
        if (err) {
            console.error("Failed: " + err);
            return;
        }
        if (stdout)
            console.log(stdout);
        if (stderr)
            console.error(stderr);
    });
```

Which (as expected) results in this:

```
/bin/sh: 1: route: not found
```

I tried the [--add-host solution](https://blog.codeship.com/using-the-add-host-flag-for-dns-mapping-within-docker-containers/), But how do i know what IP Number to use?
In other words, where does this IP come from?

```
--add-host=testing.example.com:10.0.0.1
```

Comment: The purpose of bridges is to communicate containers, not containers with their host. So I'm not sure if it fits your case.

Comment: thanks for the comment, But, a bridge implements quite a handful share of the network stack. Therefore it can open connections to ANYwhere (`testing.example.com` ) I don't see how only the host can be excluded from this.